# How to make addActionListener and add work?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I've looked through quite a few posts that had to do with addActionListener but none of them really helped me with this. I'm just trying to get this program to run after tinkering with it for a while and I still have no idea how to get my "addActionListener" and "add" to work, so any help would be appreciated

The problems I have are about halfway down and and then near the bottom, both with arrows pointing to them. I am new to this site so I don't know how to make the code numbered if I even can :( sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for any help!

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class Phone extends JFrame
    {
       private JButton keyJButton[];
       private JPanel keyJPanel;
       private JPanel lcdJPanel;
       private JTextArea lcdJTextArea;
       private String lcdOutput = "";
       private int count;

       // constructor sets up GUI
       public Phone()
       {
          super( "Phone" );

          lcdJTextArea = new JTextArea( 4, 15 );
          lcdJTextArea.setEditable( false );
          lcdJPanel.add( lcdJTextArea );

           JButton keyJButton[] = new JButton[15];

          // initialize all digit key Buttons
          for ( int i = 3; i <= 11; i++ )
             keyJButton[ i ] = new JButton( String.valueOf( i - 2 ) );

          // initialize all non-digit key Buttons
          keyJButton[ 0 ] = new JButton( "Send" );
          keyJButton[ 1 ] = new JButton( "clr" );
          keyJButton[ 2 ] = new JButton( "End" );
          keyJButton[ 12 ] = new JButton( "*" );
          keyJButton[ 13 ] = new JButton( "0" );
          keyJButton[ 14 ] = new JButton( "#" );

          keyJButton[0].addActionListener;//<------------------THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING                  //                                                                 PROBLEMS

                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
                {
                   lcdOutput = "Calling...\n\n" + lcdOutput;
                   lcdJTextArea.setText( lcdOutput );
                } // end method actionPerformed
              // end new ActionListener
        // end addActionListener call

          keyJButton[ 1 ].addActionListener(

             new ActionListener()
             {
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
                {
                   if ( lcdOutput.length() == 0 || 
                      lcdOutput.substring( 0, 1 ).equals( "C" ) )
                      return;
                   else
                   {
                      lcdOutput = lcdOutput.substring( 0, ( lcdOutput.length() - 1 ) );
                      lcdJTextArea.setText( lcdOutput );
                   } // end else
                } // end method actionPerformed
             } // end object ActionLstener
          ); // end addActionListener call

          keyJButton[ 2 ].addActionListener(

             new ActionListener()
             {
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
                {            
                   lcdJTextArea.setText( " " );
                   lcdOutput = "";
                } // end method actionPerformed
             } // end new ActionListener
          ); // end ActionListener call

          for ( int i = 3; i <= 14; i++ )
          {
             keyJButton[ i ].addActionListener(

                new ActionListener()
                {
                   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
                   {
                      lcdOutput += e.getActionCommand();

                      if ( lcdOutput.substring( 0, 1 ).equals( "C" ) )
                          return;

                      lcdJTextArea.append( e.getActionCommand() );
                   } // end method actionPerformed
                } // end new ActionListener
             ); // end addActionListener call
          } // end for loop

          // set keyJPanel layout to grid layout
          keyJPanel = new JPanel();
          keyJPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 5, 3 ) );

          // add buttons to keyJPanel
          for ( int i = 0; i <= 14; i++ )
             keyJPanel.add( keyJButton[ i ] );

          // add components to container
          add( lcdOutput, BorderLayout.NORTH );//<---------------THIS AS WELL
       } // end Phone constructor
    } // end class Phone
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You haven't got the right syntax when attempting to add an ActionListener to keyJButton[0]. It looks like you have it right for the others but this line:

```
keyJButton[0].addActionListener;
```

Should be replaced with:

```
keyJButton[0].addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
```

Don't forget to close any additional brackets and braces.

You also can't add lcdOutput to your frame because it's a String and not a component of some sort. Maybe you could construct a label and add that instead?

```
add( new JLabel(lcdOutput), BorderLayout.NORTH );
```

Edit: Just realised that line 27 will throw an NPE. You need to initialise lcdJPanel before you add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an actionListener to a button like so:

```
keyJButton[0].addActionListener(this);
```

then in the actionPerformed method, do something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) 
                {
                   Object target=e.getSource();

                   if (target == keyJButton[0] )
                   {
                      //do stuff
                   }
                   if (target == keyJButton[1] )
                   {
                         //do stuff
                   }
                }
```

Using this option, you dont need to create a `new ActionListener()` for each button. Just add an actionListener to each button and use if statements in the actionPerformed method to decide which button was clicked.